# Why does the Eurostar not show youth pricing?

Tags: eurostar

I'm trying to book tickets on the Eurostar, and the website says that youth (under 26) pay a reduced rate. Then they ask the ages of my party and I indicate 2 adults and 2 youth, but when I get the final invoice, it prices the youth at the same rate as adults:

[image]

What's going on here?!

Comment: And even before they phased them out there was always very little availability in the specific fare class used for youth fares. As a travel agent of 15 years i can count on 1 hand how many times i was able to offer the youth fares

Comment: Remember that it is possible to find this fare for £58 - if you can be flexible about when you travel!

Comment: Technically the title is wrong. It *does* show youth pricing, quite explicitly too. It just so happens to be the same as adult pricing.

Comment: @Strawberry And how would you find this fare for £58? On the official website too? It's quite rare to see a price this low.

Comment: @Ela782 Well, since you ask, I can see a fare on Monday 9th September (to Paris) returning to London the following day for £29 each way.

Answer (score 52):

I was writing this while on infinite hold with Eurostar support, but they eventually answered and told me that they are phasing out youth fares but haven't yet updated the website. Meanwhile, they're priced the youth fares same as the adult fares.

The representative also told me that youth fares were only a few pounds cheaper than adult anyway, so this doesn't make much difference in practice anyway.